# Want to put gobal filter outside of primeNg table component

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primneNg  and now want to add global filter, but the problem is i need to add this filter in another component. Both these component are deep nested in other component.

what i did is took a reference of table component using  `@ViewChild('table') table: TableComponent;` and pass it to child and did `table.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')`. **I am getting "Identifier 'filterGlobal' is not defined" error.**

filter.compononent.html

```
<input (input)="table.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" pInputText type="text"  placeholder="Search..." />
```

filter.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('table') table: TableComponent;
```

table.compoent.html (app-table)

```
<p-table #table value]="data" sortMode="single" reorderableColumns="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="350px" [(selection)]="selectedItems">
```

dynamic-listing.comoponent.html

```
<app-filter></app-filter>
<app-table></app-table>
```

both of these filter and table component are getting called in another component(dynamic-lising.component.html).  component also getting called under many other components.

Answer (score 0):

The table component has to be defined within the filter in order for it to be accesible.
You can access the table using viewchild in the dynamic-listing component.
You could try having the  component inside the filter.component.html

Comment: I am able to access the table using viewcChild. But i cant change the component location, this is the problem.